# HTML5 Application Cache vs Standard Browser Cache

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache, html5-appcache, http-caching

I am in the process of implementing an "offline" option of a web application and am uncertain wether to proceed with the HTML Application Cache or the browser cache.

There are several aspects of the Appcache that make it attractive, name the ability to leverage the FALLBACK section to support the loading of a "minimal" version of the app if the client is disconnected.

My primary concern with the Application Cache is it's longevity and browser support. While I am willing to only support modern browsers, I fear the Application Cache may become phased out in future HTML specs. This fear is founded in this line of the current spec :

```
The following features are at risk and may be removed due to lack of implementation.
       Application Cache
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

Any insight into this would be greatly appericiated.

Comment: If you need to implement an offline web application, application cache is really the only player in town. Regular browser cache doesn't kick in when the user has no internet connection. There will still be backwards compatibility when (if?) it ever gets phased out, at least for a bit.